# Resizing of subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIView`, which contains a `UIImageView` subview. The subview fills the parent view frame.

I am zooming the parent `UIView` from a point in the center of the screen, from a width and height of 0, 0 up to full size.

The subview won't stretch to fill the parent, it just remains full size the whole way through.

I've tried various combinations of `contentMode` and `contentStretch`, but nothing I do seems to work.

Help gratefully received.

Comment: do u want to zoom in/out the subview along with parent view?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to zoom the subview with the parent view. The subview is exactly the same size as the parent and fills the parent frame.

Answer (score 2):

If by `zooming` you mean animating the superviews frame, you have to set up autoresizing correctly. The superview must be set to do autoresizing:

```
superview.autoresizeSubviews = YES;
```

... while the image view must have its mask set up correctly:

```
imageview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried that. The subview behaves strangely. It now becomes huge and massively oversized, but the parent view still behaves perfectly as it did before.